# Cast to object from join

Tags: c#, .net, linq

i have join which returns a list of an triple objects. Can I somehow cast to list of this objects?

```
var result = entities.Join(...).Join(...).Join(.. new {a=a, b=b, c=c}).ToList();
//how to cast like:
var multipleList = (List<{ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC}>)result;
```

Comment: Isn't 'result' exactly that?

Comment: ok, what is the type `List<{ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC}>` ?

Comment: is that work for you ???

Answer (score 2):

```
var multipleList = 
    result.SelectMany(x => new object[] { x.a, x.b, x.c })
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this, create list of tuple

```
 var data = (from e in entities
             ///code to join entities...
            select new Tuple<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC>
                (
                     e1,//enitry of ClassA
                     e2,//enitry of ClassB
                     e3//enitry of ClassC
                 )).ToList();
```

Read about tuple here : [Tuple Type in C#4.0](http://pranayamr.blogspot.ca/2012/12/tuple-type-in-c40.html)

Comment: Instead of `new Tuple<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC>( ... )` you can also use the static `Create<,,>` method, like so: `Tuple.Create( ... )`. The advantage is that the type arguments `<ClassA, ClassB, ClassC>` can be omitted because they can be _inferred_ by the compiler when one uses a generic _method_.